# Best container for C++ class objects

Tags: c++, class, user-interface, containers

I'm coming from a couple of years of experience in Java, and I was wondering, what's the best way to store class objects in C++?

The basic array doesn't quite have the functionality I need, is there a type of array that's more like Java's arraylist?  I noticed that vectors seemed to be a popular choice, kind of like a mix between an arraylist and stack?

I'm trying to make a little board game and I wanted my game driver to operate by placing my pieces in a container of positions which are in another container, any suggestions?

I was also wondering what would be the best [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) for this kind of project? I tried googling the question and I got a list of possibilities. Is there one that's good just for basic shapes, and user buttons, nothing too complicated?

Comment: Use vector<class>

Comment: I'm curious where the stack in your analogy comes from.

Comment: Yes std::vector is probably closest to Java's ArrayList class. Both are backed by arrays, have unbounded space, initial capacity, etc..

Comment: @chris I'm guessing the op noticed the push_back and pop_back methods.

Comment: noticed some push pop functionality

Comment: @user2426318 Coming from Java, I really recommend that you to read a Standard Template Library (STL) tutorial. STL is a term that is often informally used to refer to c++ containers, iterators, and algorithms. Any container that has amortized growth at the back will have push_back and pop_back methods. Similarly, any container that has amortized growth at the front will have push_front and pop_front methods. For example, the deque container can extend out in either direction, so it has all four methods.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist equivalent in C++ is the std::vector (they are very close).

If you don't know which data structure to use, get std::vector. It's the best practice in C++ (IIRC, Scott Meyers/Bjarne/[Sutter(item 76)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) recommend to use std::vector by default).

Comment: Well, it is not *necessarily* the best in practice, but it's a low-overhead default choice that can always be revisited later on in case of performance issue. Still, do mind that it does not support access by key or unicity of elements (by itself): it's just a sequence of elements.

Answer (score -2):

Herb Sutter [recommends deque](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) in some cases.

There's also something called [segmented_array](http://i42.co.uk/stuff/segmented_array.htm).

Comment: Never heard of this `std::segmented_array` and I [couldn't find it in cppreference either](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=segmented_array).